# Why did the T-Rex help Claire?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-world

In the climax of [*Jurassic World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_World) (2015), when the genetically modified dinosaur Indominus Rex kills all the raptors trained by the hero, Claire releases the T-Rex from the cage. It assists in defeating Indominus Rex.

The T-Rex is not trained like the raptors. Why did the T Rex help the protagonists, instead of just eating them?

Comment: Related http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35402/why-didnt-t-rex-and-velociraptor-attack-each-other

Comment: One of the raptors survives, *Blue* and makes an appearance in the sequel *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the same Tyrannosaurus Rex from the first Jurassic Park film. In the first movie, Dr. Alan Grant rescues two kids from getting attacked by using a flare to get the T-Rex's attention. When Claire throws the flare at the Hybrid Rex, she is indicating to the T-Rex to attack it. See the picture below:

[image: Jurassic Park (1993)]

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't 'help' her. It is lured into the area with the Indominus Rex and the two happen to have a fight. The flare is used, as they know from past experience, the T-rex will follow them.

Comment: In fact, the T-Rex in Jurassic World is the same Rex from Jurassic Park. http://www.slashfilm.com/jurassic-world-easter-eggs/2/

Answer (score 5):

I think its a throwback to the Original Jurassic Park's ending where the T-Rex kills the Raptors and saves the protagonists.

In Jurassic world here we have the Raptor, T-Rex and mosasaurus taking out the fearsome Indominus Rex and assisting the protagonists and also the reason why we don't see a T-Rex in this movie until the very last scene.

Answer (score -1):

I think the T-Rex helped them because he knew there was only one king so the T-Rex, the velociraptors and the humans worked together to save the Earth from Indonimus Rex

Answer (score -1):

I think that is obvious.1st, The T. Rex's (Rexy), eyesight is based on movement. So it followed the flair. And 2nd, Rexy saw the I. Rex as a threat/challenger. So of coarse she engaged. If the I. Rex wasn't there, the main characters would be dead.

Comment: And everyone knows every Dino is female. Sorry guys, just like today, in the prehistoric age, makes must have been dicks